# Area of an annulus through integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So, I have an annulus with inner-hole radius $r_1=1$ and outer-hole radius $r_2=5$.

To be exact, I have the area of only half of the annulus in this assignment, from $\theta_1=-\frac{3\pi}{4}$ and $\theta_2=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

I have a problem in transforming the integral function into coordinate form, and here's what I'm doing:

$$\iint_A y\,dx\,dy=\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\int_{r_1}^{r_2}(\text{stuff})\,dr\,d\theta.$$

The it's $(\text{stuff})$ I have a problem with.

I'm thinking something along the lines of (outer circle) $x^2+y^2=5^2$ (inner circle) $x^2+y^2=1.$

$$y=\sqrt{25-x^2}\implies \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\int_{r_1}^{r_2}\sqrt{25-r^2} \,dr\,d\theta,$$

but this here is not the correct answer. Also, it is very possible to solve this without integral, but that would defeat the point.

Comment: If this wasn't polar, I'd say: the double integral calculates a volume above the plane, so what height should you pick to get the area? Unfortunately, polar double integrals have an extra factor in the integrand because the area of a small "rectangle" with small angle range and radius range is proportional to the radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the area of the whole annulus, $$\iint\limits_{1 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 25}1\,dx\,dy = \int_{1}^{5}\int_{0}^{2\pi}1\cdot r\, d\theta \, dr.$$
If $\theta_1 \leq \theta \leq \theta_2$, then this reduces to
$$\int_{r=1}^5 \, \int_{-\frac 34\pi}^{\frac \pi 4}1\cdot r\, d\theta \, dr = \left(\frac 14 + \frac 3 4\right)\pi\cdot\frac 12 (5^2 - 1^2).  $$

Az @Zubzub said, the $r$ comes from the absolute value of the determinant of the Jacobian of the map
$$(x,y) \mapsto (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta).$$

The Jacobian is $$\pmatrix{ \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -r\sin\theta &r\cos\theta}, $$ so its determinant is $r(\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta) = r$.

Comment: In your answer you have $\int_1^5 \int_0^{2pi}d\theta dr$ instead of vise versa, what are the implications of it? (And also, I'm getting wrong answer with simply assigning the $stuff$ as $1*r$

Comment: The order doesn't matter, because of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem). What do you get, and what should you be getting?

Comment: [Picture](https://i.gyazo.com/a695bb029ba7097ab60cd8574e7c43b5.png) Here the first empty box represent the polar coordinate form and the second box the plain answer (12*pi), but it will only give out right/wrong answer on return. I've tried different variations where $1*r$ is the main idea, but I've not found an acceptable answer for it.

And this is not important or anything, but I'm just a bit baffled by the math happening here because of the answer not being accepted

Comment: @Grak Oh, I see... does a simple $r$ work?

Comment: Nope, nothing I tried ended up working, but thanks anyway - I got the answer and idea right but not the "right answer", so to speak

Answer (score 3):

Using polar coordinate you would get 
$$
\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \int_{r_1}^{r_2} 1\ \color{red}{r} dr d\theta
$$
Where we have the additional $\color{red}{r}$ coming from the Jacobian of the change of coordinate.

---

However if you want to stick with classical cartesian coordinate, one could first try to rotate the annulus to have it in the position of an upper semi-circle and then use the function definition of the upper semi-circle : $y = \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$ giving us :
$$
\int_{-r_1}^{r_1} dx \int_{\sqrt{r_1^2 -x^2}}^{\sqrt{r_2^2 - x^2}} dy\ 1 + 2 \cdot\int_{r_1}^{r_2} dx \int_0^{\sqrt{r_2^2 - x^2}} dy \ 1 \overset{(*)}{=} 12 \pi
$$
$(*)$ Thanks Mathematica because the computations are not that easy, especially the simplification to $12 \pi$. That's why I would strongly suggest using polar coordinate.

Comment: Strangely enough I'm not getting through with simple "$r$" replacing "$stuff$", am I misinterpreting this somehow or am I probably asking the wrong question?